# Save and Retrieve an Image using Qt

Tags: qt

In fact I found some useful article related to my issue, but not exactly, I will try detail my problem

I have a table with tow columns id as integer and pix as blob

I have a form with label and two buttons open and save

I try to open a picture into label, then I have to save into database table when I click save

Also, I'm looking to retrieve the image again to label if I added navigation buttons as next and previous.

Any help please ?

Answer (score 2):

Here's a short example for saving a QImage into the database:

```
// Converting image to byte array:
QByteArray bytes;
{
    QBuffer buffer (&bytes);
    buffer.open (QBuffer::WriteOnly);
    image.save (&buffer, "PNG");
}

// Writing data into the database:
QString id_string = id == -1 ? "NULL" : QString::number (id);
QSqlQuery query ("REPLACE INTO images "
                 "(id, image) VALUES (:id, :image)");
query.bindValue (":id", id_string);
query.bindValue (":image", QString (bytes.toBase64()));
if (!query.exec()) throw some_exception;
```

So basically you need to convert an image into the byte array, and then just use SQL query to save it in the database. Take note that I'm working on this very issue in my program as we speak, so the code above may be imperfect. Hope this helps.

Comment: IMO there is no need to convert to base64 when the image column is a BLOB.

Comment: At the first I would like to thank you, it seems a perfect code. But I'm not that a professional programmer, so I need more help from you. Please be patient.

Let's break it as parts, in the first block 
I included both  QByteArray and QBuffer
then a question comes here, why we need the two braces ? I mean could we write it as

QbyteArray bytes;
QBuffer buffer(&bytes);
buffer.open(QBuffer::WriteOnly)

At the end whats image represent for ?

Thank you very much again

Comment: @Septagram I wanna retrieve the image from the database and display it. How can this be done?